# How do I set up dnsmasq so a device connected to the router can ssh into a device connected through the desktop?

Tags: ssh, networking, dnsmasq

I was experimenting with some setups to allow my devices to be physically beside each other, and speed up my workflow so I wouldn't need to sit next to my router in the cold part of the house to send files over ftp, do ssh, the usual functions of a headless server.
My initial solution was to use a PCI ethernet card I found, plug said card into Machine A, physically connect the computers together, and follow [This article](https://www.softprayog.in/troubleshooting/connecting-two-computers-with-ethernet-lan-cable) to allow machine B to access the network through Machine A.

to summarize:

Machine A is the desktop with 2 ethernet ports, ip address on the network `192.168.1.9`

Machine B is a laptop with 1 ethernet port, my target, ip address `192.168.2.193`

I followed the instructions for setting up dnsmasq properly to allow B to acccess the internet through A. So far, the only way I can SSH to B is by setting up a tunnel through the IP of A, forwarding port 22 of the "internal" address of `192.168.2.193`

Machine B can access the external web, and behaves normally internet-wise

my ssh command:
`ssh -L 8080:192.168.2.193:22 webmaster@192.168.1.9 -N`

I can provide any extra information needed to solve this, if there's more information required.

**EDIT**

updated iptables with the suggested inputs for machine A

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
val_input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.2.0/24       anywhere             multiport dports bootps,bootpc /* dhcp */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:domain /* dns-tcp */
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.2.0/24       anywhere             udp dpt:domain /* dns-udp */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain val_input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bal_output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**EDIT 2**
output of `ip a` on machine A

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:54:3d:e8:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.1/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp1s5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.1/32 scope global enp1s5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::208:54ff:fe3d:e8fd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp1s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:90:78:9a:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.9/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21e:90ff:fe78:9a97/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**EDIT 3**
output of `ifconfig` on machine B

```
[jaz@Jaz-Jackson ~]$ ifconfig

........

ens5f5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.193  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::1a0f:d7d2:b678:665f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:cf:30:71:b2:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 379032  bytes 142855672 (136.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 510236  bytes 65400716 (62.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 32

......
```

Comment: Could you please also show the MAC address for the laptop? This is relevant for the dnsmasq dhcp config. It should be sufficient to do `ip a` on Machine B.

Comment: ah, I apologize for not following your request. I updated with `ifconfig`'s output instead of `ip a`

Comment: Cool, I've updated the answer to add a minimal dnsmasq config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about turning Machine A into a router. DNSMasq is one useful component, allowing the router to hand out IP addresses to dhcp clients, and offering a nameserver. However, this is not sufficient by itself.

1. You need to enable packet forwarding in the kernel. Run `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` with root privileges, eg sudo. Make it permanent by putting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` somewhere under `/etc/sysctl.d/`, eg put it in a file called "routing.conf". You can check the current value by running `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`.
2. You need Network Address Translation (NAT), aka masquerade. If you're using iptables, you'll need a stanza at the top which looks something like this (for outward-facing interface `enps1s8`):

   ```
   *nat
   :PREROUTING     ACCEPT  [0:0]
   :INPUT          ACCEPT  [0:0]
   :OUTPUT         ACCEPT  [0:0]
   :POSTROUTING    ACCEPT  [0:0]

   -A POSTROUTING  -o enp1s8 -j MASQUERADE

   COMMIT
   ```
3. In addition to enabling forwarding in the kernel and setting up NAT, you also need to tell the firewall to accept requests for packet forwarding, so for iptables a couple of rules likes so:

   ```
   # Forward between client LAN and external WAN
   -A FORWARD                                            -i enp1s5 -o enp1s8 -j ACCEPT
   -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -i enp1s8 -o enp1s5 -j ACCEPT
   ```
4. Finally, there needs to be rules for how to route packets. This isn't a firewall thing, instead I would use iproute2. It's convenient to put it in a script:

   ```
   $ cat /usr/local/sbin/add-lan-route
   #! /usr/bin/ip -b

   addr add 192.168.2.1 dev enp1s5
   route add 192.168.2.1/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev enp1s5
   ```
5. Machine B (the laptop) also wants to talk to dnsmasq on Machine A (the desktop). So some more iptables rules are needed to open up the desired ports. To keep things organised, it's a good idea to set up a "chain" for this, but if you don't feel confident with iptables, the most direct way to get what you want is something like this:

   ```
   -A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m multiport --dports 67,68 -m comment --comment "dhcp"    -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.2.0/24              --dport  53    -m comment --comment "dns-tcp" -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.2.0/24              --dport  53    -m comment --comment "dns-udp" -j ACCEPT
   ```
6. Finally, you want Machine B's dhcp client to pick up the right IP address, which can be handed out by dnsmasq on Machine A. A basic dnsmasq config could look like this:

   ```
   interface=enp1s5
   dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.254,255.255.255.0,1h
   dhcp-host=20:cf:30:71:b2:7e,192.168.2.193,1h
   cache-size=2048
   ```

The cache size isn't really important, it's just a suggestion which you can modify or discard. The rest allows anything plugged into enp1s5 to ask for an IP address, and if it's Machine B's MAC, it will get your preferred IP address. You should also have a look through the default dnsmasq config since it has a lot of commentary to think about.

With all those steps in place, you should hopefully have Machine A functioning as a router which can grant a nameservice and an IP address to Machine B, and NAT the internet connection through enp1s8.

Comment: This looks very promising. thank you. If I do recall correctly, the article I linked in the question goes through most, but not all, of what you put here, so I should be able to add in those extra functions without having to undo everything else I did. I'll attempt to work with this throughout today and will mark your answer as accepted if it resolves.

Comment: just for clarification this will expose octet 2 to octet 1, so I can connect to any .2 addresses while on the main network?

Comment: Also, you specified a script to be placed in `/usr/local/sbin/` must this be automatically executed every time I reboot, or does it run on its own? I don't think I have used sbin before.

Comment: `Cannot find device "lan0"
Command failed /usr/local/sbin/add-lan-route:3
`
apologies for the "issues on top of issues" issue I am giving. I think I need to specify the bridge interface instead of lan0

Comment: @Jaz The answer originally used placeholder names for the interfaces, since the question didn't provide them. Now that you've given `ip a`, I've updated the answer to use `enp1s5` instead of `lan0` and `enp1s8` instead of `wan0`.

Comment: I realise I should give a basic dnsmasq config, but it will require the MAC address for Machine B.

Comment: Thank you for the update. May I ask whether or not this setup will allow say... a smartphone running termux on the main network, 192.168.1.0/24, to ping 192.168.2.1, and get an appropriate response? I fear that it'll be dropped since the real router doesn't know what .2 is, but Machine A does.

Comment: @Jaz It's theoretically possible, but depending on your operating systems maybe not very easy. If you had terminal/ssh access to all devices, including (I'm guessing here) the router at 192.168.1.1 which Machine A talks to for internet, then it could be done by updating the routing rules in the right places. But I would suggest raise it as a separate question if you really need to go down this path.

Comment: in that case, This answers my question enough so that I can operate it cleanly. The best action is probably to forward B's port 22 to an uncommon port on A, and then forward that to the internet OR do an ssh chain like I used to.